# Replacing IP address with DNS in Oracle connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I am trying to replace hardcoded IP with DNS in Oracle connection string in the config file.
My connection string is as follows....

```
<add name="Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MerchantOracleDB.csdl|res://*/MerchantOracleDB.ssdl|res://*/MerchantOracleDB.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;CONNECTION TIMEOUT=300;DATA SOURCE=(Description=(address_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.179.12.13)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MERCHANTTest)));PASSWORD=Merchant;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=MerchantDBA&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

How can I replace the IP with DNS if my DNS is MerchantDNS.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the part with IP address (10.179.12.13) with the DNS name you desire, for example "MerchantDNS" (without quotes). This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10835/protocoladd.htm).
Just make sure that this DNS do exist.

Comment: And all kinds of connection string goodness can be found at https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: Thanks, Will check with the provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. One workaround can be reading the registry to find out the ServerName configured in the DSN. This will give you Host, Port and Service name as Host:Port/Service.
The path in the registry would be (64 bit): HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI<your Data source name>

Comment: Also in the connection string, you can directly provide
Data Source=Server:Port/Service;